# SQL Server 2012 database stored and need to be restored on SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

As the title says, I need to restore a SQL Server 2012 database (express) to a SQL Server 2008 R2 production database.

I cannot find a way to do so.

The scripting seems to fail due to the size of one of the tables having about 300.000 records.

Any way to "downgrade" the 2012 database?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: **[Restore SQL Server 2012 backup to a SQL Server 2008 database](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20588/restore-sql-server-2012-backup-to-a-sql-server-2008-database)**

Answer (score 0):

You **CANNOT** do this - you cannot attach/detach or backup/restore a database from a **newer version** of SQL Server (2012) down to an **older version** (2008 R2) - the internal file structures are just too different to support backwards compatibility. There's no way, no trick, no hack, no magic to make this happen. Period.

You can either get around this problem by

- using the same version of SQL Server on all your machines - then you can easily backup/restore databases between instances
- otherwise you can create the database scripts for both structure (tables, view, stored procedures etc.) and for contents (the actual data contained in the tables) either in SQL Server Management Studio (`Tasks > Generate Scripts`) or using a third-party tool
- or you can use a third-party tool like Red-Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to do "diffing" between your source and target, generate update scripts from those differences, and then execute those scripts on the target platform; this works across different SQL Server versions.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. Thats what I was afraid of. Michael